# ReactNative add Router v 4 with default navigation to a page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-v4

I see there is a lot of different versions of React and Routers.

There seems to be like a 10 NPM packages for implementing it.
I also see React package has already an implementation for NativeRouter.

I try to use it, but my app dumps:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <NativeRouter>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
  </NativeRouter>
    );
  }
```

[Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZAE3.png)

Before I was using MemoryRouter this way, but could not find out, how to navigate to the second page:

```
  <MemoryRouter 
  initialEntries={['/home']}
  initialIndex={0}>
  <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
```

What should I use for native: native or memory router? Do you know any easy example or piece of code to see how it can be implemented?
Could you please advise something? The React documentation is not really helpfull (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)